# Is it safe to run rm -r "$HOME/.wine"?

Tags: rm

I looked on google for how to uninstall Wine. I found something and it told me to enter these:

```
rm -r "$HOME/.wine"
rm  $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -r "$HOME/.local/share/applications/wine"
rm $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
```

After entering them I looked in the comments saying it might nuke your home folder. Is this true? I can't see anything wrong right now.

Comment: Partially true. It will nuke your home folder if you run `rm -rf "$HOME"`. So I suggest you to first read the whole article before attempting to run something which includes `rm` in the command.

Comment: Thanks. Did it damage anything and will I need to re-install Ubuntu?

Comment: @RedStar12 nope, that's unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

Let's understand how `rm -rf` command works first. It removes everything in a given directory and the directory itself, so if you give it path `$HOME/directory_1/directory_2/` the `directory_2`  will be gone along with its files. The rest of the path will be safe. Heres' an example:

```
$ tree somethings/                                     
somethings/
└── subdirectory_1
    ├── a
    └── b

1 directory, 2 files
$ rm -rf somethings/subdirectory_1/                    

$ tree somethings
somethings
```

So as far as your commands go:

- `rm -r "$HOME/.wine"` only removed `.wine` directory
- `rm  $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*` only took care of all files starting with `wine` string in `$HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged` folder
- `rm -r "$HOME/.local/share/applications/wine"` removed the `wine` folder only
- `rm $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*` got rid of the files starting with `wine` in  `$HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories` folder
- `rm $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.xpm` nuked all `.xpm` files.

In other words they're sufficiently safe.

---

What me and Rinzwind have discussed in the comments and Ask Ubuntu chatroom, is that it's possible to alter `$HOME` variable. Yes, it is possible, but if you intentionally alter `$HOME` , you need to keep that in mind; otherwise, it's not `rm`'s fault and let's be honest - it's plain stupid from user's point of view. Commands work only on the path you give it, so give the commands proper path.

Other potential issues is spaces. If you have space in your home folder name, like `/home/My User`, then without quotes around `$HOME` the shell will think you're giving it two arguments, `/home/My` and `User`. This effect is known as word splitting. So always quote your variables like `"$HOME"`

Comment: this is assuming $HOME was not changed by the user  ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind explain what do you mean please ?

Answer (score 0):

Partially true. It will nuke your home folder if you run `rm -rf "$HOME"`. So I suggest you to first read the whole article before attempting to run something which includes `rm` in the command.

And no. As far as we can see, it didn't hurt anything essential or necessary for the correct system operation.

You have so far, removed WINE's configuration files, which WINE will rebuild when necessary and/or reinstalled.

So calm down and good luck!